# ADO Adding record to table only adding one value

Tags: asp-classic, ado

So i'm using ADO to add data into a sql database, here's my raw code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

     <h1>
      Teacher registration 
      </h1>
      <form name="teacherReg" action="http://hr-computing/public/AlexS/Tests/login.asp" method="POST">
      First name:<input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
      Last name:<input type="text" name"lastname">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
<%
 set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 conn.Open ={ private }
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "Select * from teachers", conn


sql="INSERT INTO teachers (firstname, lastname)"
sql=sql & " VALUES "
sql=sql & "('" & Request.Form("firstname") & "',"
sql=sql & "'" & Request.Form("lastname") & "')"

on error resume next
 conn.Execute sql,recaffected
 if err<>0 then
   Response.Write("No update permissions!")
 else
   Response.Write("<h3>" & recaffected & " record added</h3>")
 end if
 conn.close
 %>
 </body>
 </html>
```

It's working but only adding the value of firstname into the table, not lastname aswell, I can't see where i'm going wrong, any help guys?

Comment: can you check the sql before you do the execute ? and see what it actually contains ?

Comment: and, why do you need that select statement there? are you listing the teachers?

Comment: and remove the on error resume next line for the time being

Comment: Check the name of the form element for lastname and read this...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @Fred what's wrong with the lastname form field ?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/  And MySQL is not SQL SERVER

Comment: I'm hoping this is just over-simplified for the sake of the question. You ought to look at some of the questions here related to sql-injection and some common practices like properly sanitizing inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<input type="text" name"lastname">`
to
`<input type="text" name="lastname">`

You are missing an equals sign.